# Why there is ViewState  in TextBox?

Tags: asp.net

TextBox can retain the value entered in it even if the viewstate is disabled, as LoadPostBackData event magically loads the data into TextBox at the PagePostBack. Is there a specific reason TextBox has ViewState or the ViewState has been just inherited from WebControl class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewState includes much, much more than just the text.

To clarify: if you do `Textbox1.Visible = false;` then the control will not render any html output. With ViewState enabled its full runtime state will still be passed on to the next postback, including the **Text** property, the **Visible** property and many of its other properties.

In other words, with ViewState enabled a Web Control never loses any of its state, even when the control itself is not rendered in the html output.

With ViewState disabled, the **Text** property (and all others) will lose their value as soon as you set **Visible** to False; or even if you set set **Visible** to False for its surrounding/parent control.

Answer (score 3):

[Some properties of a control are required to maintain their values between postbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx) so them can work properly. Disabling ViewState doesn't disable this behavior.


Text is the only property of the TextBox which preserves the data between postbacks, even ViewState is disabled, but on the other side, the ToolTip, as example, uses pages ViewState to preserve the data. If ViewState is disabled, ToolTip won't preserve the data between postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBox value is not maintained via the ViewState. It is maintained through form data.